# Why cookie is not set in request?

Tags: javascript, express

I read a lot of entries but anything response my question.

I'm setting the cookie and auth works out. I can log in with www and non-www domain. But when I logged in and javascript makes requests the cookie is not present in the headers in non-www domain. If I'm in the www domain the same request has the cookie.

Why can I log in with both domains (www and non-www) but when I make request with javascript from non-www domain the cookie is not present in the headers?

I set a auth cookie like this:

```js
res
  .status(200)
  .cookie('cookie_name', token, {
    domain: '.myDomain.com',
    httpOnly: true,
    maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 3,
    secure: !!(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production')
  }) // 3 days
```

Comment: Same port and protocol? You have httpOnly set

Comment: Yes same port and protocol... :/

Comment: The point is that I can log in with both domain and my backend check if cookie is present with valid token. If I can enter then the cookie is set it. I also check with dev tools. The cookie is not present if the request is made with javascript..

Comment: Setting `httpOnly` means that JS requests will not be able to see the cookie. If you need to have the cookie present in requests from JavaScript, set `httpOnly` to `false`

Comment: @MihaiPotra but why is it present when I make the same request from www domain?? I think the same but if we are right the js request from www domain should fail too

Comment: It's present to the browser only. But the browser prevents you from accessing any cookie with the HttpOnly flag set, via JavaScript. https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6265#section-4.1.2.6

Comment: You may have the same cookie set somehow without the flag on the www domain, and it remained there?

Comment: Okay, I discover something. If I log in with www domain, the problem appear in non-www domain. If I log in with non-www domain the problem apear in www domain. I think this should not happening because I set the cookie domain like: .domain.com accepting all submains... Redirect always to www submains seems the fastest solution...

Comment: Login should work fine, because you do a request to the server, and the server sets the cookie. That cookie will always be accessible by the browser, regardless of the request coming from a subdomain or not. But it will never be accessible to javascript requests, meaning that when you do a JS request to the server, it will not include it in the `Cookie` header sent to the server. However, when you do the same request via browser (e.g. open up the page, or refresh), the browser will send the Cookie header with it.

Comment: Basically, if you check login status via JS, it should fail (e.g. `xmlhttprequest` and `fetch` will get "401 unauthorized"), but accessing the same url in the browser should give you/render a logged in page

Comment: Correct! Thank you very much!